# Mac Pro with ATI RADEON 5770 - Ubuntu 12.04 x64 and 3 monitors

Tags: 12.04, ati, multiple-monitors, radeon

Does anyone know whether I'll be able to run 3 monitors on my Ati Radeon HD 5770 with latest version of Ubuntu.

I'm completely new to running Ubuntu as my operating system, but after today's disaster with Snow Leopard, which has crashed 3 times I've decided to finally give it a go and I truly hope it will be the system I've been looking for for many years.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu on Macbook Pro(I am assuming you can do this), install the proprietary graphics driver from additional driver. Search it on dash. Then select the appropriate one for your card. If you want to install the drive manually

[What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Then watch  youtube video for multiple(video shows duel setup) monitor setup.

[Possible Dual Monitor Fix (AMD Catalyst) - Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yyL8CyEe7Q)

Comment: It's not the Macbook - it's Mac Pro (tower).

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 12.04 on the Mac Pro? Or do you need help installing Ubuntu 12.04 on Mac Pro?